# Framework or service like Votebox

Tags: dropbox, user-feedback

I love the Votebox section on the support site for Dropbox.  It lets users suggest features and prioritize development.

I always assumed it was powered by a third-party service (kind of like Getsatisfaction.com), but from what I can tell it's proprietary.

Does anyone know of an open-source project, SaaS service, or the like, sporting similar features and polish?

[image: Votebox screenshot]

Comment: Could you suggest a more appropriate Stack Exchange site for me to post this question?